# How to treat certain words as delimiters in nltk Python?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize the below text with stopwords('is', 'the', 'was') as delimiters

The expected output is this:

```
['Walter', 
 'feeling anxious', 
 'He', 
 'diagnosed today,' 
 'He probably', 
 'best person I know']
```

This is the code which I trying to make the above output

```
import nltk 
stopwords = ['is', 'the', 'was']

sents = nltk.sent_tokenize("Walter was feeling anxious. He was diagnosed today. He probably is the best person I know.")

sents_rm_stopwords = [] 

for sent in sents:
    sents_rm_stopwords.append(' '.join(w for w in nltk.word_tokenize(sent) if w not in stopwords))
```

My code output is this:

```
['Walter feeling anxious .',
 'He diagnosed today .', 
 'He probably best person I know .']
```

How can I make the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem considers both stopwords and line delimiters. Assuming that we can define a line by the symbol `.`, you can introduce that to multiple splits by using `re.split()`.

```
import re
s = "Walter was feeling anxious. He was diagnosed today. He probably is the best person I know."
result = re.split(" was | is | the |\. |\.", s)

results
>>
['Walter',
 'feeling anxious',
 'He',
 'diagnosed today',
 'He probably',
 'the best person I know',
 '']
```

Because we are using both single `.` and `.`  with a whitespace after, the split results will return an additional `''`. Assuming that this structure of sentences are consistent, you can slice the results to get your expected results.

```
result[:-1]
>>
['Walter',
 'feeling anxious',
 'He',
 'diagnosed today',
 'He probably',
 'the best person I know']
```